# Absolute position is not working

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to place a div with id 'absPos' in absolute position in relation to its parent div. But it is not working, the div is placed at the top left corner of the page.

My code sample is as follows

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="padding-left: 50px;">
            <div style="height: 100px">
                Some contents
            <div>

            <div style="height: 80px; padding-left: 20px;">
                <div id="absPos" style="padding: 10px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; background-color: red;"></div>
                Some text
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you help me to solve this issue. 
In my actual case instead of the red background color I've to place a background image.

Regards

Comment: Not an answer to the question in particular, but may be helpful to others experiencing a similar issue to what I was that led to this page: make sure you're not forgetting the units in your position specification. I accidentally used "bottom:79;" instead of "bottom:79px;", and was puzzled why it was at the top of the page.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Elements with absolute positioning are positioned from their `offsetParent`, the nearest ancestor that is [also positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Types_of_positioning).  In your code, none of the ancestors are "positioned" elements, so the div is offset from body element, which is the `offsetParent`.

The solution is to apply `position:relative` to the parent div, which forces it to become a positioned element and the child's `offsetParent`.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="padding-left: 50px;">
            <div style="height: 100px">
                Some contents
            <div>

            <div style="height: 80px; padding-left: 20px; position: relative;">
                <div id="absPos" style="padding: 10px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; background-color: red;"></div>
                Some text
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue with this is parent div's css is applied to child div's css, like opacity, etc. difficult to debug.

Comment: And so folks, as you can see, with CSS, absolute means relative.

Answer (score 11):

If you are placing an element with absolute position, you need the base element to have a position value other than the default value.

In your case if you change the position value of the parent div to 'relative' you can fix the issue.

Comment: My element's nth-parent has a position other than the default, but I need my element to be placed absolutely on top left of the window, so exactly the opposite of this question. Can it be helped? Why does it work like that?

Answer (score 7):

You need to declare the parent div either `position: relative` or `position: absolute` itself.

`relative` is what you're looking for in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You need to give parent div `relative` position first:

```
<div style="height: 80px; padding-left: 20px; position:relative;">
```

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you were trying to position an element over another element, the floating element needs to be inside of the other, not as siblings. Now your `position:absolute;` can work!

Answer (score 0):

You can also Apply Position:absolute to the Parent Div. Total Code below

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="padding-left: 50px;">
            <div style="height: 100px">
                Some contents
            <div>

            <div style="height: 80px;position:absolute; padding-left: 20px;">
                <div id="absPos" style="padding: 10px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; background-color: red;"></div>
                Some text
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```