# Aurelia composed absolute elements

Tags: css, aurelia

In a view rendered by `<compose>` within another view, I have a div that I want to take over the whole browser window in response to a user action. This CSS

```
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0;
bottom: 0; right: 0;
```

didn't work. The answer to [Absolute position is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830486/absolute-position-is-not-working) suggests that I have exactly the opposite problem. Most likely my div is a child of a block element that specifies relative position.

So far the options apparent to me are...

- Re-parent it in the DOM
- Have another view directly parented on the page and use complicated messaging to proxy back and forth

I don't think much of either of these. I'm not certain of the implications of reparenting with a largely binder controlled DOM and the other option is ridiculously complicated.

Anyone got any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few solutions for this case:

1. You can use CSS position `fixed` on the element you want to go full page.
2. You can move the element that needs to be in full page in a separate tree from the root element in the view where it resides.
3. Create a custom attribute, decorated with `@templateController()`, and upon binding , insert the view into document body instead of its template position.

Solution 1 is the best, if your mobile support targets have no issue with position fixed.