# putting css over image

Tags: html, css, fivem

I have a problem with HTML and CSS I can't put my notch over the image I used as a shell in FiveM. I have also tried to put it in one class it didn't work tried to put over the img src also didn't work any ideas?

```css
.notch {
  position: absolute;
  width: 144px;
  height: 27px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 73px;
  z-index: 4;
  background: black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 24px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 24px;
}

.camera {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  top: 9px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 119px;
  background: #0d4d71;
}

.speaker {
  height: 6px;
  width: 60px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  background: #171818;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container disableSelection">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="phone-frame">
  
  <div class="phone-container phone-background">
    <div id="notch" class="notch">
      <div class="camera"></div>
      <div class="speaker"></div>
    </div>
```

Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrvCV.png

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. What you have doesn't make sense. Also revise to explain your desired outcome better.

Comment: It looks like we're missing some CSS here too as I don't see some of your classes in your CSS posted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Absolute position is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830486/absolute-position-is-not-working)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Given I don't know the code in full, I suspect you can't because when you use

```
.notch {
   position: absolute;
   ..
}
```

This makes .notch relative to its parent, however its parent is not the image but .phone-container which is a sibling of the given image.

Comment: what should i channge it to?

Comment: That _doesn't_ necessarily make `.notch` relative to its parent. Also, you haven't provided a solution.