# How can I move this button in React to be on the card I've created?

Tags: css, reactjs, button

I have a Button component created which has a JS file and a CSS file which is working perfectly (with variations of style). I have added an instance of the button in this advert card but I cannot get it to move up but I don't think it's the method, I think it's not getting the Button in the CSS file related to the advert card. Is it possible to style this button with two different CSS files as I don't want to move all instances of the button obviously, only the one in the advert card.

Below is a screenshot highlighting what should be in the card and where the button should move to (obviously will hide overflow, this is to show you the button).
[Advert Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fObm.jpg)

Here is the relevant code items, but can supply more context if needed but seemed unnecessary as everything else works. (To be clear, the button itself works and is correctly styled as per Button.css but I cannot seem to change it's position in another CSS).

AdvertItem.js
`<Button buttonStyle="btn--blue">Add Now</Button>`

Holidays.css
`.Button { position: absolute; bottom: 500%; }`

I've tried referencing in the CSS as .Button, .btn--blue and adding a ClassName to the Button and referencing that but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to style your `React` components with class selector, you still need to add a class for `<Button>` to properly adapt the `css`. It should be something like this (with `JSX`):

```
<Button className="button" buttonStyle="btn--blue">Add Now</Button>
```

---

So what if you have tried this and nothing works? Then, it's time to check the multiple things below:

1. Confirm that you have imported both stylesheets, preferrably the `holiday.css` after the first stylesheet.

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/holiday.css" />
   ```

2. Inspect whether the `styles` have been applied through browsers' `Inspect` tools. A `CSS` rules is overwritten if the below shows:

   [image: overwritten_css_rule_example]

   And that you can check the [CSS specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) between two `CSS` blocks simply by hovering over it:

   [image]

   Compare the specificity and see what have overwrite the rule (as I could not do this unless you provide both `css` files).
3. Sometimes, if the `offsetParent` of `Button` component is not positioned, the `position: absolute` will simply has no effect.

   Set the `offsetParent` to `position: relative` to make sure it is positioned on the `DOM` (others have already explained this issue well in this question: [Absolute position is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830486/absolute-position-is-not-working)).

Hope the above answer helps.

Comment: Thanks for your great suggestions, however, none of these points are working. Holiday.css is imported in the holidays JS file and everything else this references is being styled, so it must be something up with the button. I've inspected the styles and nothing relevant is being overridden. And I've tried the position: relative in the .btn and .btn--blue which it is inherited from

Comment: @EveNordinstorm Hi, thank you for your reply. I'd suggest checking the `display` of your CSS, and where you put them; if possible, try using `flex` and `grid` instead of `position: absolute`; however, if you want to know why there is a problem with `position: absolute`, you can post your code onto the website - if it suits your need, you can even copy and paste it up, so to take a look of it. Hope your project is well.